# Finding the frequency of the a value not included in a frequency table

Tags: statistics

[image]

Using the above table represents the amount of money that the students receive .Find the number of students who received one standard deviation above the mean .

My turn

The mean is $10.22$ and the standard devaition is $1.38$ ,so we need the number of student that an amount more than $11.6$

The range is $4$ , then assume that the data is equally distributed we have

$\frac{4}{85} = \frac{3.6}{f}$

So $f= 77$ , so the number of students who received less than $11.6$ is $77$ , so the required is $85-77 = 8$

Is this correct ?

Comment: If you want the number of students who received more than 11.6, then you want the number of students that received 12, which is 20.

Comment: The correct answer in the book is 18 but i do not know how does it come @William M.